# Getting error after ubuntu 12.04 update

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I was using 'ubuntu 12.04'. Windows7 is already installed in the system. I am getting the following error when I try to update Ubuntu (`sudo get-apt update`)

```
             GNU GRUB version 1.99-Z1ubandu3.16
Minimal BASH-like line editing supported.For the first word,TAB lists possible command completions.Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

I uninstalled and installed ubuntu but I am still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to your difficulty, but I'm having difficulty refraining from venting a simply question which I feel needs asking.

**Simple Solution:**
*Update Ubuntu without using terminal/bash:*

1. Manually open your Ubuntu Update Manager
   howto:  Press your windows key and type "upd" sans quotes and press enter.
2. Click on the "Check" button and the wait for it to verify if your system is up to date.
3. DO NOT skip the preceding step!
4. After it has completed its check, click install updates.
5. Close the update center
6. DONE!

My simple vent question follows: Why is it I keep encountering people here who insist upon using the terminal and bash commands to accomplish simple tasks in an easy-to-use GUI linux operating system such as Ubuntu?  It seems to me that if there are so many people obsessed with command line use, they shouldn't bother with a GUI linux at all.